# SQL Server Linked Server openquery for WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, openquery

I am trying to write a query to get the delta between my server and Linked Server. So I wrote the following which worked until:

```
Select MD5 FROM  ServerA A
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT 1
FROM [LinkedServer].[Database].[dbo].[Files] fi
WHERE A.MD5High = fi.MD5High AND A.MD5Low = fi.MD5Low
)
```

However this pulls all the data from LinkedServer to my server which causes my server to run out of resources. So my next attempt was to perform the query on the linked server

```
Select MD5 FROM  ServerA A
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT 1
FROM OPENQUERY( [LinkedServer] , 'SELECT [LinkedServer].[Database].[dbo].[Files] fi
WHERE fi.MD5High = ' + A.MD5Low + ' AND  fi.MD5Low= ' + a.MD5Low + '')
)
```

However the syntax in the second query is incorrect and I can't figure the correct syntax.

I appreciate any direction

Comment: Try `SELECT TOP(1) 1` in the first query.

Comment: Dale wouldn't Select Top(1) 1 return only one row?

Comment: That's enough for `EXISTS`.